# Regex on PHP not working correctly

Tags: php, regex

```
$productid = preg_match('/^.*?_/', $ProductPath);
ShowProduct($productid);
```

The problem is $productid is always 1 and never changes no matter what the $productpath is, forinstance if productpath is `/store/gst/prod_4` it still equals 1

Comment: read the manual for preg_match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe this will help

```
preg_match( '/^.*?_(\d+)/', $ProductPath, $matches );
$productid = $matches[1];
```

Answer (score 2):

preg_match returns the number of matches. That means your pattern matches once. If you want to have the result you need to use the third parameter of preg_match.

[See here the docs on php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
preg_match('/^.*?_/', $ProductPath, $matches);
$productid = (int) $matches[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to get the first few characters until the `_` underscore, you can use [`strtok`](http://php.net/strtok) instead:

```
$productid = strtok($ProductPath, "_");
```

(Using the regex only makes sense if you (1) use [`preg_match`](http://php.net/preg_match) correctly, (2) also verify that those first few characters are actually numbers `\d+`.)

Answer (score 0):

```
$productid = preg_match('/^.*?_/', $ProductPath, $match);
print_r($match);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$productid = preg_match('#(prod_)([0-9]+)#', $ProductPath);
ShowProduct($productid[1]);
```